# how to undelete my deleted question

Tags: support, deleted-questions, vote-to-undelete

I have answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771381/configure-business-activity-monitor-with-api-manager) question and mentioned a link to the answer. A moderator deleted the question saying

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the
>   essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.
>   Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

I edited the answer to include the information in the linked page. but still it is a deleted one. could someone help me to undelete it? Thanks

Comment: I don't think it should be undeleted since it still doesn't contain the needed information in case the link breaks. Anyway, you can flag the post to get moderator's attention.

Comment: I have included the answer. anyone can solve the question by not going to the link

Comment: @ben75 :I will flag to get moderation attention. thanks for the helps